Installing translations for Plymouth on (K)ubuntu
Whenever I see the "Installing Updates" plymouth screen, it's in English. Is there a way to install translations? I compared the Plymouth themes themselves with ones I have installed on Fedora (where the updating screen is in German, the language I want it to be in), the themes seem to be the same - the text in the file is in English, so it seems to get translated through another way. Is is possible to do this in Ubuntu?
